# MobilePhone as HyperLink

Tags: hyperlink

[image]I have an requirement, would like to make mobilephone field on contact object to hyperlink with phone icon so user can click on the phone number to make a call to the number. Please help me here.

I added a formula field the contact object and made it as hyperlink. Now I want this to happen for contact mobilephone field

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, this question is probably too broad to be a good fit for this site. Generally speaking, the more details you include, the better. Some details, like whether you're working in Salesforce classic, or Lightning Experience, can change the approach that you need to take. Showing us what you've tried so far (which commonly means sharing the code you've developed so far), and what you've researched tends to make questions better received. The goal of this site, after all, is to help you overcome problems, and not do your work for you.

Comment: If you have more details to add to your question, you can add them by making an [edit]. Comments are limited in length, formatting options, and are best thought of as temporary.

Comment: In short, you can do this. But you will need to provide where is this field displayed - classic, lex, or you have built a custom vf page or lightning component and such details.

Comment: I want this to happen on standard contact page layout for mobilephone field

Comment: The image is when you enable CTI in SF

Comment: Oh.. will it be enabled by default.. I have done that specifically other than installing the app from app exchange

Comment: For normal phone fields that icon would be shown. When you click on that automatically the CTI phone app will open

Comment: on clicking the number its taking me to make a call from skype

Answer (score 2):

Create new formula field to show phone number hyperlink.

If phone is your contact number field, then the formula field will be something like

```
HYPERLINK(('tel:'+Phone), Phone)
```

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13662222/4121395

You cannot directly hyperlink on Mobile Phone field in SF. You have to build Chrome plugin or custom SF component/page for it.

Comment: Able to do it with custom formula field.. but want this to happen with standard mobile field on contact object

Comment: You cant do that, You have to build a chrome plugin for it. Or build a custom SF UI.

Comment: I have seen in a app from appexchange where it is done.. so thought of would be done on standard page.. attached the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Use field TEL. or simply create a text field (A) and create a formula field (B) and write the following formula :

''+A__c+';

Comment: I want it for contact standard mobilephone field